# Show textarea if selected item in listbox changes

Tags: javascript, listbox

I have a listbox, and I want to show a textarea if I have a selected item, it is so simple, but my code isn't working, can any one help me?

**Listbox code :**

```
<select onchange="change(this)" name="idUser" class="form-control">
      <c:forEach items= '${listeU}' var='p' >
           <option value="${p.getIdUser()}"> ${p.getIdUser()} - ${p.getNom()} ${p.getPrenom()}</option>             
      </c:forEach>    
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
function change(obj) {
      var selectBox = obj;
      var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
      var textarea = document.getElementById("text_area");

      if(selected === '1'){
            textarea.show();
      }
      else{
         textarea.style.display = "none";
      }
}
```

**Item to show :**

```
<textarea id="text_area"  type="text" name="text_area" style="display: none"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** is a jQuery and you're using pure JS so you should replace it by :

```
textarea.style.display = "block";
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function change(obj) {
  var selectBox = obj;
  var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
  var textarea = document.getElementById("text_area");

  if(selected === '1'){
    textarea.style.display = "none";
  }
  else{
    textarea.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="change(this)" name="idUser" class="form-control">
    <option value="1"> option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> option 3</option>
</select>

<textarea id="text_area"  type="text" name="text_area" style="display: none"></textarea>
```

Comment: @Bashir is that not what you looking for?